# cannot find an algorithm for this

Tags: algorithm

The Initial Condition of the problem is like this:

```
1200 : 480 and 800 : 320
```

I need an equation(or equations) for changing the value but 320 is fixed.

for example: if change 1200->500 and 800->500 then the equation should be 500:320 and 800:320

example 2 :
1200 : 384 and 1000 : 320

example 3 :

```
  1000  : 400 and 800 : 320
```

example 4 : 
           2000 : 640 and 1000 :320

Comment: Your question is not clear. Nor does it show any effort on your part.

Comment: I couldn't decode what you are asking. I tried, I really did.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication ?

Comment: For defining a task you should define specific terms, set limitations (including constants, equations and inequations) and the target... "I need  an equation(or equations) for changing the value". But no equation changes anything! "320 is fixed" Sure, because it is a number. Maybe some variable is fixed to 320?  What one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

> numerator = 2.5 * denominator